# Printing ocaml function after compiling

Tags: ocaml

It's my first day with ocaml. Enjoying it so far. I wanted to figure out if there is a way to print the result of a function. Here's an example based on [Project Euler #5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5).

My code is:

```
let rec gcd a b =
  if b==0 then a
  else (gcd b (a mod b));;

let rec myans n anssofar=
  if n==1 then anssofar
  else (myans (n-1) ((anssofar*(n-1))/(gcd anssofar (n-1))));;

Printf.printf "%d\n" (myans 20 20)
```

This works fine. I then compile it using:

```
$ ocamlc -o PE0005 PE0005.ml
```

And then run it using

```
$ ./PE0005
```

And it spits out the answer.

Now, suppose I wanted to work out myans 10 10. It seems perverse to do what I have been doing which is to go back, edit the last line to

```
Printf.printf "%d\n" (myans 10 10)
```

and then recompile and rerun. The function has already been defined and compiled. Is there some way I can print out the answer without recompiling?

Any hints and tips are welcome.

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem but please do not use the `==` operator. Though it works on integers its behavior will create intricate bugs you will not understand. What you should use is a simple `=`.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to run your code in the toplevel (the OCaml read/eval/print loop). This lets you experiment more easily.

```
$ ocaml
# #use "PE0005.ml";;
val gcd : int -> int -> int = <fun>
val myans : int -> int = <fun>
232792560
- : unit = ()
# myans 10 10;;
- : int = 2520
```

Another possibility is to rewrite your code to get the argument from the command line. This is what you would do in practice for a compiled command-line program.

```
let main () =
    if Array.length Sys.argv < 3 then (
        Printf.eprintf "need two integer arguments\n";
        exit 1
    ) else (
        Printf.printf "%d\n"
            (myans (int_of_string Sys.argv.(1)))
    )

let () = main ()
```

This is how it works when you run it:

```
$ ocamlc -o PE0005 PE0005.ml
$ ./PE0005 20 20
232792560
$ ./PE0005 10 10
2520
```

Comment: If you're looking into a toplevel, i'd recommend `utop` which is kinda like the regular ocaml one but with much more features: https://opam.ocaml.org/blog/about-utop/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Sys.argv`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Sys.html?VALargv) to get command line arguments and pass the values at runtime.